# Averaged value of product of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

*Note: the following question comes from Alex Meiburg via Faceboook and was found via his work with the Legendre Polynomials in quantum machine learning.*

---

Let $P_k$ be the $k$-th Legendre Polynomial.

The following identity is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality_and_completeness):
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2k + 1}{2} P_k(x)P_k(y) = \delta(x-y)$$
but can we prove the following (experimentally derived) observation:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2k+1}{2}P_k\left(x\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$

Comment: Do you know that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$ is a classical probability distribution, the [arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution) ? Therefore, it wouldn't be surprizing that there is a probabilistic proof of your identity using for example this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0792.pdf).

Comment: This is awesome. I know I said I thanks on Facebook already, but again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be proved.

The first useful observation is that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k(x)^2$ is bounded, e.g. via the generating function [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415885/83537). The claim thus reduces to showing:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kP_k(x)^2 = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Note the domain of $x$ allows the substitution $x \mapsto \cos x$ (since such a substitution can be inverted since $x \in (-1,1)$), allowing the claim to be rewritten as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kP_k(\cos x)^2 = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}$$
By symmetry it suffices to suppose $x \ge 0$, so it suffices to prove:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kP_k(\cos x)^2 = \frac{\csc x}{\pi}$$
To this end, we may throw out finitely many terms in the sum and apply the [asymptotic form of $P_k(\cos x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Asymptotics) (see the comments for a formalization of this idea) to find:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kP_k(\cos x)^2 &\sim \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k \text{ large enough}}^{n-1}k\frac{4}{2\pi k\sin\left(x\right)}\cos\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2} 
\\&=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k \text{ large enough}}^{n-1}\frac{\cos\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}}{\sin\left(x\right)}
\\&\sim \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{n}\csc\left(x\right)\left(2\left(n-1\right)+\csc\left(x\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}-2x\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}-2nx\right)\right)\right)\\&\sim \frac{\csc x}{\pi} \end{align}
$$
and we are done. Note the trigonometric sum can be calculated by writing everything as complex exponentials, splitting into geometric series, and then converting back.

Comment: Is $\alpha=x$? When substituting you have both $\alpha$ and $x$. The asymptotic form of $P_k$ is valid for large $k$, but you use it for small values too.

Comment: @Gary Sorry yeah, typo from copying the equations from elsewhere. I suppose I could label the sums better, but the idea is to throw out finitely many terms until you get the sum within epsilon of whatever value of want (since finitely many terms won't matter). Since the convergence asymptotically is of the form $O(k^{-3/2})$, we have quite a bit of wiggle room while maintaining convergence

Comment: Is the summation in terms of trigonomatric functions true if the sum strats at large enough $k$?

Comment: @Gary Roughly the argument I had in mind is that from Bernstein's Inequality we know:
$$\begin{align}
|P_{n}(x)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{1/4}}.
\end{align}$$ so
$$\frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}kP\left(k,\cos x\right)^{2}\right| \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}k \frac{2}{\pi n}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{\pi n}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{n}}k = O(1/n)$$ so we can throw out all the terms up to $\sqrt n$ without changing the limit.

Comment: The sum up to $\sqrt n$ of the trigonometric sum is given by:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{n}\csc\left(x\right)\left(2\left(\sqrt n-1\right)+\csc\left(x\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}-2x\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}-2 \sqrt n x\right)\right)\right) = O(1/\sqrt n)$$ so we can add back in those terms without changing the limit, which is what I meant in the post

Comment: It seems OK, if you replace the last $=$ with $\sim$ in your answer. Am I right?